# Why does MOVE command in DOS treat wildcard patterns oddly in this case?

Tags: command-line

I am using the "move" command with a wildcard pattern in the CMD prompt under Windows 7.

In my source directory, I have the following files:

```
 movie1.avi
 movie1.avi_metadata
 movie2.avi
 movie2.avi_metadata
```

If I type the command `move source\*.avi dest` it will move all four files even though I would expect it to only move the two `*.avi` files and not the `*.avi_metadata` files.

As expected, `move source\*.a dest` and `move source\*.av dest` don't move any files.  However when the length of the extension for the wildcard pattern is 3 characters, it will move all extensions that begin with those first three characters.

Is this a bug in the "move" command or expected behavior and is it documented anywhere?

---

Edit: John Watts notes that this is probably do to "short" filenames.

Is it possible then to make commands in the CMD interpreter only operate on long filenames and to ignore short filenames?

Comment: Does windows 7 still create 8.3 names? Because those would match *.avi for all four files.

Comment: Ah... short file names... you bite me in the butt.  Thanks John.  BTW, I wonder who downvoted this.  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: It probably belongs on superuser. It is more appropriate to move it than downvote, but they may not have enough rep for that.

Comment: Well, it's certainly something that affects BATCH programming.  I'm not even sure how to move it to a different StackExchange site :-(

Comment: See [this  rule from MS DOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx), still relevant today for compatibility.

Comment: you could disable creation of short filenames on ntfs using fsutil: `fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1`. This affects only files created after the change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a file to archive folder in cmd using wildcards](https://superuser.com/q/517486/173513) and [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/173513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe DIR /B through FINDSTR to filter out the unwanted files. You can process those results using FOR /F.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d source\*.avi^|findstr /lie .avi') do move "source\%F" dest
```