# Move a file to archive folder in cmd using wildcards

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management

I'm using this command:

```
move C:\folder\*.txt C:\folder\archive\*.txt
```

I'm trying to move multiple files to an archive folder using the `*.txt` but I get an error that states it cannot find the file specified.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

syntax is `move C:\folder\*.txt C:\folder\archive`

Comment: all this while I was using / instead of \

Answer (score 2):

The `move` command does not allow wildcards in the destination, which must be an existing directory if you're moving more than one file.  (The syntax for `move` is different than for `rename`, which may be confusing you. )  Here's an example:

```
> dir /w
 Volume in drive C is Windows7
 Volume Serial Number is E441-3A51

 Directory of C:\Users\Nicole\Desktop\MoveExample

[.]      [..]     file1    file2    [folder]
               2 File(s)             27 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  507,369,046,016 bytes free

> move file* fold*
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

> move file* newfolder
Cannot move multiple files to a single file.

> move file* folder
C:\Users\Nicole\Desktop\MoveExample\file1
C:\Users\Nicole\Desktop\MoveExample\file2
        2 file(s) moved.
```